# Swift xcode: How do I draw on the same view as a text field plus a list of buttons?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Screenshot of what I'm trying to create: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmuFw.png)

NOTE: There's no need to look at the code below if you decide to run the project because all the classes I posted below are inside the dropbox zipped project file.

Each of the squares on the bottom selects a different color and there's an invisible square that selects the type of shape off to the right of the green one. After the user selects one of these shapes, the user will be able to draw in a certain part of the screen.

Entire project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3uottk2erjcryo/SwiftXcodeProject888.zip?dl=0

If you run the project, create an account, then click sign in, then click one of the rows, the app will crash and get the following error message:

```
2016-03-11 15:07:04.530 finalProject2[11025:1028122] <UIView: 0x7f86334592a0; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f8633495310>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f863345a550>>'s window is not equal to <finalProject2.RowTableViewController: 0x7f86336b3a20>'s view's window!

File slot 1

File slot 2

File slot 3

File slot 4

File slot 5

File slot 6

File slot 7

File slot 8

File slot 9

File slot 10

File slot 11

File slot 12

2016-03-11 15:07:06.723 finalProject2[11025:1028122] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<finalProject2.MainProjectScene 0x7f86334ae2a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key buttonForShape.'

*** First throw call stack:

(

0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010835ce65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a46adeb objc_exception_throw + 48

2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010835caa9 -[NSException raise] + 9

3   Foundation                          0x000000010894d9bb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288

4   UIKit                               0x00000001090d6320 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88

5   UIKit                               0x0000000109304f41 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109

6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010829d4a0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224

7   UIKit                               0x0000000109303924 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864

8   UIKit                               0x00000001090dceea -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381

9   UIKit                               0x00000001090dd816 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178

10  UIKit                               0x00000001090ddb74 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138

11  UIKit                               0x00000001090de2e7 -[UIViewController view] + 27

12  UIKit                               0x0000000109888f87 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 87

13  UIKit                               0x00000001090adf62 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 133

14  UIKit                               0x00000001090f0c8c -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4002

15  UIKit                               0x00000001090f3f2c -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 489

16  UIKit                               0x00000001090f3a3b -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 179

17  UIKit                               0x00000001090f90df -[UIViewController _showViewController:withAction:sender:] + 280

18  UIKit                               0x0000000109547874 __66-[UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 147

19  UIKit                               0x0000000109670f5c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 460

20  UIKit                               0x0000000109670d5f -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82

21  UIKit                               0x0000000109671023 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156

22  UIKit                               0x000000010908acee -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1775

23  UIKit                               0x000000010908afb3 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 388

24  UIKit                               0x0000000108f534a2 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 317

25  UIKit                               0x0000000108f66c01 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 95

26  UIKit                               0x0000000108f72af3 _afterCACommitHandler + 90

27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108288367 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23

28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001082882d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391

29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010827df2b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147

30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010827d828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488

31  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e332ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161

32  UIKit                               0x0000000108f47610 UIApplicationMain + 171

33  finalProject2                       0x000000010815017d main + 109

34  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010af7392d start + 1

35  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1

)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

MainProject scene class:

```
import UIKit



weak var FirstFileNameTextField: UILabel!

enum ShapeType: String

{

    case Line = "Line"

    case Ellipse = "Ellipse"

    case Rectangle = "Rectangle"

    case FilledEllipse = "Filled Ellipse"

    case FilledRectangle = "Filled Rectangle"

    case Scribble = "Scribble"

}

 let shapes: [ShapeType] = [ .Line, .Ellipse, .Rectangle, .FilledEllipse, .FilledRectangle, .Scribble ]



class MainProjectScene: UIViewController

{

     var row: Row?







    @IBAction func PressedSaveAs(sender: UIButton) //this is the save as function that I would like to know how to change



    {



        //1. Create the alert controller.



        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Name/rename your file:", message: "Enter a filename to name/rename and save your file", preferredStyle: .Alert)



        //2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.



        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in



            textField.text = "Your file name"

        })



        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler:

            {

                (action) -> Void in

                let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField

                print("Text field: \(textField.text)")

                // rows.cell.textLabel?.text = textField.text

                CurrentFileName = textField.text!

                rows[IndexPath.row].FileName = textField.text!

                rows[IndexPath.row].UserText = self.TextUserScrollEdit.text!



        }))



        // 4. Present the alert.

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)





      //  rows[indexPath.row].FileName = rows.cell.textLabel?.text



       // rows[i] = textField.text



               // if let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? MainProjectScene {



              //  if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {



              //  if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {



               // detailViewController.row = rows[indexPath.row]



    }





    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)

    {



        if let r = row

        {



            row!.FileName = r.FileName



            row!.QuartzImage = r.QuartzImage



            row!.UserText = r.UserText

            rows[IndexPath.row].UserText = self.TextUserScrollEdit.text!        }

    }





    override func  viewDidLoad()

    {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        TextUserScrollEdit.text = rows[IndexPath.row].UserText

        // FacebookButton.addTarget(self, action: "didTapFacebook", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)



    }



    @IBOutlet weak var TextUserScrollEdit: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var NewFileButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var TwoDQuartzButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var YouTubeButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var TwitterButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var OpenFileButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var SnapChatButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var FacebookButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func PressedTwoDQuartzButton(sender: UIButton) {



    }



    @IBAction func PressedSnapchatButton(sender: UIButton){



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.snapchat.com/")!)



    }



    @IBAction func PressedYouTubeButton(sender: UIButton) {



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/")!)



    }



    @IBOutlet weak var InstagramButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func PressedFacebookButton(sender: UIButton) {



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.facebook.com")!)



    }

    @IBAction func PressedInstagramButton(sender: UIButton) {



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.instagram.com/")!)



    }



    @IBAction func PressedTwitterButton(sender: UIButton) {



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://twitter.com/")!)



    }



    @IBOutlet weak var SaveAsButton: UIButton!













      // @IBOutlet weak var shapeButton: ShapeButton!



    @IBOutlet weak var canvas: CanvasView!



        @IBOutlet var colorButtons: [UIButton]!



    @IBOutlet weak var shapeButton: ShapeButton!



        @IBAction func selectColor(sender: UIButton) {

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0,

                usingSpringWithDamping: CGFloat(0.25),

                initialSpringVelocity: CGFloat(0.25),

                options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

                    for button in self.colorButtons {

                        button.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - 58

                    }

                    sender.frame.origin.y -= 20

                }, completion: nil)

            canvas.color = sender.backgroundColor!

            shapeButton.color = sender.backgroundColor!

        }



        @IBAction func selectShape(sender: ShapeButton) {

            let title = "Select Shape"

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)



            for shape in shapes {

                let action = UIAlertAction(title: shape.rawValue, style: .Default) { action in

                    sender.shape = shape

                    self.canvas.shape = shape

                }

                alertController.addAction(action)

            }

            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }



}
```

ShapeButton class:

```
import UIKit





class ShapeButton: UIButton {





    let shapes: [ShapeType] = [ .Line, .Ellipse, .Rectangle, .FilledEllipse, .FilledRectangle, .Scribble ]



    var shape: ShapeType = .Line {

        didSet {

            setNeedsDisplay()

        }

    }



    var color: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor() {

        didSet {

            setNeedsDisplay()

        }

    }



    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.

    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        // Drawing code

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)

        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2)



        let x1: CGFloat = 5

        let y1: CGFloat = 5

        let x2: CGFloat = frame.width - 5

        let y2: CGFloat = frame.height - 5

        let rect = CGRect(x: x1, y: y1 + 5, width: frame.width - 10, height: frame.height - 20)

        switch shape {

        case .Line:

            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x1, y1)

            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x2, y2)

            CGContextStrokePath(context)

        case .Ellipse:

            CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, rect)

        case .Rectangle:

            CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect)

        case .FilledEllipse:

            CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect)

        case .FilledRectangle:

            CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        case .Scribble:

            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x1, y1)

            CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context,

                x1 + 80, y1 - 10,           // the 1st control point

                x2 - 80, y2 + 10,           // the 2nd control point

                x2, y2)           // the end point

            CGContextStrokePath(context)

        }

    }





}
```

Canvas view class:

```
import UIKit



/*

    This program is for Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2

*/





class CanvasView: UIView {





    var shape: ShapeType = .Line

    var color: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    var first :CGPoint = CGPointZero

    var last  :CGPoint = CGPointZero

    var points: [CGPoint] = []



    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.

    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        // Drawing code

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)



        let rect = CGRect(x: first.x, y: first.y, width: last.x - first.x, height: last.y - first.y)

        switch shape {

        case .Line:

            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, first.x, first.y)

            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, last.x, last.y)

            CGContextStrokePath(context)

        case .Ellipse:

            CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, rect)

        case .Rectangle:

            CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect)

        case .FilledEllipse:

            CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect)

        case .FilledRectangle:

            CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        case .Scribble:

            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, first.x, first.y)

            for p in points {

                CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, p.x, p.y)

            }

            CGContextStrokePath(context)

        }

    }



    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first {

            first = touch.locationInView(self)

            last = first

            points.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            if shape == .Scribble {

                points.append(first)

            }

            setNeedsDisplay()

        }

    }



    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first {

            last = touch.locationInView(self)

            if shape == .Scribble {

                points.append(last)

            }

            setNeedsDisplay()

        }

    }



    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first {

            last = touch.locationInView(self)

            if shape == .Scribble {

                points.append(last)

            }

            setNeedsDisplay()

        }

    }



    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard, you have two bindings for the clear button. It looks like you had a binding called buttonForShape and then decided to rename it or something.  The binding from the storyboard was not removed.

[image: This is how your bindings should look]

On the storyboard, go to the bindings panel and click the x to remove the extra binding.

Comment: Thank you that worked. But now when I try to draw on the screen I get the window is not equal /view not in the hierarchy error? Any ideas on this?

Comment: Looks like that is caused by presentViewController() in your RowTableViewController. That view controller isn't in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Do not mutate this question. It was answered to your satisfaction. If you have some other problem with your project, then post a separate question.